# Memory leak with jquery fixed table header, AJAX setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I use the below fixedtableheader plugin on a golf leaderboard page that uses AJAX and setInterval to fetch score changes from the server.  Without the plugin everything works well, with the plugin, there is a constant memory leak that during the course of the day make Firefox go from 60MB at start to 1.5GB before end of day and crash.  Can anyone spot any memory leaks in this code?

The page in question is http://scoring.pgalinks.net/leaderboards/lobby.cfm?from=so

```
jQuery.fn.fixedtableheader = function (options) {
var settings = jQuery.extend({
    headerrowsize: 1,
    highlightrow: false,
    highlightclass: "highlight"
}, options);
this.each(function (i) {
    var $tbl = $(this);
    var $tblhfixed = $tbl.find("tr:lt(" + settings.headerrowsize + ")");
    var headerelement = "th";
    if ($tblhfixed.find(headerelement).length == 0) headerelement = "td";
    if ($tblhfixed.find(headerelement).length > 0) {
        $tblhfixed.find(headerelement).each(function () {
            $(this).css("width", $(this).width());
        });
        var $clonedTable = $tbl.clone().empty();
        var tblwidth = GetTblWidth($tbl);
        $clonedTable.attr("id", "fixedtableheader" + i).css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "top": "0",
            "left": $tbl.offset().left
        }).append($tblhfixed.clone()).width(tblwidth).hide().appendTo($("body"));
        if (settings.highlightrow) $("tr:gt(" + (settings.headerrowsize - 1) + ")", $tbl).hover(function () {
                $(this).addClass(settings.highlightclass);
            }, function () {
                $(this).removeClass(settings.highlightclass);
            });
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == "6.0") $clonedTable.css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "top": $(window).scrollTop(),
                    "left": $tbl.offset().left
                });
            else $clonedTable.css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "top": "0",
                    "left": $tbl.offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft()
                });
            var sctop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var elmtop = $tblhfixed.offset().top;
            if (sctop > elmtop && sctop <= (elmtop + $tbl.height() - $tblhfixed.height())) $clonedTable.show();
            else $clonedTable.hide();
        });
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if ($clonedTable.outerWidth() != $tbl.outerWidth()) {
                $tblhfixed.find(headerelement).each(function (index) {
                    var w = $(this).width();
                    $(this).css("width", w);
                    $clonedTable.find(headerelement).eq(index).css("width", w);
                });
                $clonedTable.width($tbl.outerWidth());
            }
            $clonedTable.css("left", $tbl.offset().left);
        });
    }
});

function GetTblWidth($tbl) {
    var tblwidth = $tbl.outerWidth();
    return tblwidth;
}
```

};

Comment: Firefox has always been notoriously bad with memory leaks. I used to not be able to have a clock because it refused to clean up `new Date()` objects. My point is, try it in a different browser and see if you get a leak there.

Comment: We did, Chrome did behave better, but we have already deployed over 200 laptops with Firefox on it an it defaults to the this home page as default.  So we are really trying to find a fix for it in Firefox.  For now, we added a meta-refresh every hour, that seems to help, but we'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: Hmm, that does sound like a disaster. One thing to consider is how likely is it that the page will be shown for a full day? Personally I don't suffer this problem because I installed Cleanmem, and it basically spend most of the time cleaning up the waste Firefox leaves.